# С большой буквы?

Tags: местоимение

"Приглашаем Вашего сына". С большой ли буквы писать слово "Вашего"?

Answer (score 1):

Вам бы чуть попонятнее вопрос формулировать...
Вы про заглавную букву в **Вы/вы**?

Зависит от того, кому пишете. Если одному родителю — то с заглавной, если обоим, то со строчной.

Оговорюсь, что это если речь идёт о сколько-нибудь официальной бумаге. При передаче устной речи (и ещё в некоторых редких случаях) заглавная может не использоваться даже при обращении к одному адресату.

Answer (score 0):

Заглавная буква В в местоимении "вы" — форма официального, вежливого обращения к одному лицу, как правило, ко взрослому человеку.

Comment: А общение на этом форуме - официальное или нет? Я всегда пишу обращение с большой буквы...